# Replace string with array elements

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
let string = 'My name is [~FIRSTNAME] [~LASTNAME]';
let nameArray = ['Peter', 'Parker'];
let patternToBeReplaced = ['[~FIRSTNAME]', '[~LASTNAME]']
```

I want to replace the `string` with the elements of `namearray` so that the string becomes `'My name is Peter Parker'`

Below is my approach to this problem -

```
patternToBeReplaced.forEach(function (match, index) {
        var output = string.replace(match, nameArray[index]);
});
```

But this is not working as expected.

Comment: you need to update the string variable.... but let has block level scope... so use arrow function instead

Comment: Yes, `string = string.replace(...`

Comment: Try using `reduce` instead of `forEach`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and use the string for the next replacement.

```js
let string = 'My name is [~FIRSTNAME] [~LASTNAME]';
let nameArray = ['Peter', 'Parker'];
let patternToBeReplaced = ['[~FIRSTNAME]', '[~LASTNAME]']

string = patternToBeReplaced.reduce((s, m, i) => s.replace(m, nameArray[i]), string);

console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a string templating system. Since you're using ECAMScript 6 syntax already, you could use the new built-in template literals.

```js
let [FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME] = ['Peter', 'Parker'];
let string = `My name is ${FIRSTNAME} ${LASTNAME}`;

console.log(string);
```

---

This will also work more cleanly when there are multiple insertions of a given label within the string.

```js
let [FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME] = ['Peter', 'Parker'];
let string = `My name is ${LASTNAME}... ${FIRSTNAME} ${LASTNAME}`;

console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
patternToBeReplaced.forEach(function (match, index) {
    string = string.replace(match, nameArray[index]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that.

```js
let str = 'My name is [~FIRSTNAME] [~LASTNAME]';
let nameArray = ['Peter', 'Parker'];
let patternToBeReplaced = ['[~FIRSTNAME]', '[~LASTNAME]']


const result = patternToBeReplaced.reduce((str, placeholder, i) => {
return str.replace(placeholder, nameArray[i]);
}, str);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `output` is a local variable, it's useless to just declaring it.
2. `replace(String, String)` would only replace the first matched pattern.

Here's my solution:

```
let replaceWithArrayElements = (patterns, replacements, targetString) => {
    patterns.forEach((pattern, i) => targetString = targetString.replace(new RegExp(pattern, 'g')));
    return targetString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First solution, keeping your base code :

```
let string = 'My name is [~FIRSTNAME] [~LASTNAME]';
let nameArray = ['Peter', 'Parker'];
let patternToBeReplaced = ['[~FIRSTNAME]', '[~LASTNAME]'];
patternToBeReplaced
.forEach((match, i)=>{
  string = string
           .replace(match, nameArray[i]);
});
```

Using `Map`:

```
let string = 'My name is [~FIRSTNAME] [~LASTNAME]';
let replaceMap = new Map();
replaceMap.set('[~FIRSTNAME]', 'Peter');
replaceMap.set('[~LASTNAME]', 'Parker');
replaceMap.forEach((key, value)=>{
  string = string.replace(key, value);
});
```

Using ES6 "template" strings:

```
/*
*Have some ways of getting the first name in "firstName"
*Have some ways of getting the last name in "lastName"
*/
let string = `My name is ${firstName} ${lastName}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string.match(/\[~\w+\]/g).forEach((item,index)=>{
  string = string.replace(item, nameArray [index])
})
```

You can use the above code for you needs